# HTML input field disable input but still POST

Tags: html, webforms

Basically i want a disable text field to show the value stored in a database but i don't want it to be editable by the user.

i've tried using `disabled="disabled"` but then it no longer POST to my form handler...

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: can please provide some more info or code ?

Comment: could you please add a tag for `asp.net` if you are using it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[docu](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1):

> In this example, the INPUT element is
>   disabled. Therefore, it cannot receive
>   user input nor will its value be
>   submitted with the form.

why do you need the value? then try the `readonly`-attribute instead of `disabled` or go for another hiddenfield.

**edit:**
it's not fully clear to me, if you use asp.net, bu if so, you could just do

```
<form submitdisabledcontrols="true" runat="server">
```

you may give it a try :)

Comment: Oh dear how did i miss readonly?!

This is exactly what i need thanks alot!

Comment: Note that if you are wanting to set readonly with JS, use `input_element.readOnly = true;`

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using a disabled field, you can enable it during form submission by handling the form `onsubmit` event, where you will enable the field and submit the form.

A second option would be to use a `readonly` field which you may cleverly make look as `disabled` via CSS.

A third option would be to use a `disabled` and a `hidden` field. Rename your `disabled` field to something irrelevant and use the original field's name for the hidden one.

Take your pick.

Comment: Unfortunately andreas beat you to the reply but thanks for your help.

i did think about enabling it on form submission but that seemed a bit tacky.

Thanks for the response and good idea about the CSS.