# MVC3/Razor - Disabled options in select tag don't post back

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a `Employee` entity that I'm binding to an "Edit" view in an MVC3/Razor application. The `Employee` entity has a property for `OccupationTypeId`. `OccupationTypeId` points to the `OccupationType` table which contains several lookup values. The natural choice would be to use `@Html.DropDownListFor` to render a `<select>` tag containing a list of Occupations.

The `OccupationType` table schema is fairly standard: `Id, Name, Description, IsEnabled`. Since OccupationTypes can be disabled, I want the `OccupationTypeId` drop down to still render disabled options so the user can always see their selection if it's disabled, but a disabled option can't be selected by the user. In other words, a user can't change an existing `OccupationTypeId` to a disabled option.

I thought about creating a `@Html` extension method to build my `<select>` tag with the options and simply tack on a `disabled` attribute to disabled options. I think that would be straight forward...

However, disabled selected options don't seem to post back to the controller method. In other words, `Employee.OccupationTypeId` would be null when I post to Edit.

Is there any way to change this behavior or is this built in to MVC 3? I thought about using hidden fields, but what if OccupationTypeId is required and I have validation enabled?

Has anyone else faced this?

Thanks

Comment: The behavior isn't built into MVC3, it's built into how forms are posted back by a browser. Only enabled, form controls are included (and even then, not all controls are always included like  checkboxes).

Comment: The following post will point you in the right direction:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351554/get-value-of-disabled-drop-down-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Have you tried readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a hidden field that gets updated when the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event occurs in the dropdown list.  This way the `OccupationTypeId` field is always passed.

```
<input name='CurrentOccupationId' type='hidden' value='@Model.Employee.OccupationTypeId' />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dropDownId').change(function() {
            $('input[name="CurrentOccupationTypeId"]').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to change this behavior or is this built in to MVC 3?
>   I thought about using hidden fields, but what if OccupationTypeId is
>   required and I have validation enabled?

It has nothing to do with MVC 3 in particular; all disabled html elements don't post back in general.

The solution I've used is to "simulate" the disable element by styling the appropriate element with CSS. You can, for example, set the element's background (or foreground) color to gray and set the [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute (when it makes sense) instead.

[See this similar thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262296/html-input-field-disable-input-but-still-post)